# How to move the column down in the increments of one?

Tags: excel

Hey Folks so I want to move each column down in the increments of one to match the age on both side. As shown in the picture. Is there a way to automate this process as I have to do that for 60 columns and 42 excel sheets

[image]

I tried to find a program to do that but I was unable to find anything as well as I dont see an option in excel to move it as a cohort as well